# Appending extra columns to Views table

Tags: 7, forms

Can anyone tell me if there's a way to use hook_form_alter, or some other approach, to insert an extra column with to a views generated table.

I am trying to insert some buttons which will update node data when a user clicks on a relevant button.

Comment: It's very easy through the UI, why do you need to do it programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can add an extra column or a field to each row of your views output. And you can choose what is best for your use case.

For a Drupal 7 site you can use -

- https://drupal.org/project/computed_field
- https://drupal.org/project/views_php
- for extra fields in plain text, [you can refer this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162343/how-do-i-add-custom-fields-in-a-view).

If you need to pass any kind of dynamic context to your custom extra field, say a node id, there are multiple ways to do that too.